# Does the "Sweeper" Combat Bonus stack across all battles or only 2+ enemy battles?

Tags: bravely-default

The Sweeper Bonus is gained from "Defeating an enemy party of 2 or more with one attack". Obviously not every battle will have 2+ enemies in it and there is nothing you can do about it. Would a battle with 1 enemy break the chain? Or does "in-a-row" mean 5/10 2+ enemy battles in a row and single enemy battles don't count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Sweeper* counter is only increased, or lost, when you encounter parties of 2+ monsters. So, you can get to *Sweeper Hero* even if every other battle is a single monster battle, so long as you KO the 2+ mob parties with a single attack.