# What do the after battle bonuses do and how do I get them

Tags: bravely-default

In Bravely Default if you meet certain conditions during battle, such as taking no damage, defeating all enemies in one turn, or defeating 2+ enemies with a single attack, you get bonuses after battle. If you do it in multiple battles in a row, you can get upgraded versions of these bonuses. What are the possible bonuses, and what benefit do they provide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three combat bonus "types": *1-Turn Victor*, *Unscathed*, and *Sweeper*. *1-Turn Victor* boosts the amount of EXP you get from the battle, *Unscathed* increases the number of JP (Job Points) you get, and *Sweeper* boosts how much money you receive.

Each of these bonuses come in three gradations: normal, *Ace*, and *Hero*. These grades are earned after 1, 5, and 10 battles in a row respectively. The amount of extra points that each combat bonus gives depends on what monsters you are fighting as they are percent increases, rather than flat increases. Normal grants a 10% increase, *Ace* is 20%, and *Hero* earns you 50% more.

Comment: Related Question about the "Sweeper" bonus: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155365/does-the-sweeper-combat-bonus-stack-across-all-battles-or-only-2-enemy-battle