# What is the best way to keep bonus chains active?

Tags: bravely-default

When you win battles in one turn, without being damaged, and/or killing every enemy with the same hit you get a battle bonus. I've noticed the more times you are able to do this in a row you can get higher tier bonuses ranging from Normal, Ace, and Hero. I learned about the bonuses in general [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155594/what-do-the-after-battle-bonuses-do-and-how-do-i-get-them).

The one that I want the most is unscathed, but I keep losing it to random rolls, things like enemy first strike or enemies attacking wildly out of "order". What are some of the strategies that you use to keep these chains rolling? I know this may be subjective, I'm just looking for some strategies to think about while I'm playing. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have all the jobs yet?

Comment: I just got Templar last night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the middle of the game, there are a few strategies:

1. Equip accessories which increase your First Strike rate (Gale Hairpin), lower enemies' First Strike rate (Alarm Earrings), and raise your Agility (Hermes Shoes / Sandals). Higher agility gives your characters a better chance to strike first. Also equip Abilities which raise your Speed and Evasion.
2. Brave all the time to maximize your damage up front.
3. Use job Abilities to prevent enemies' hits. For example: Templar's Rampart, Dragoon's Jump, and Ninja's Utsusemi.

Later in the game, bonus chains become much easier for two reasons:

1. You're (probably) over-leveled compared to all the enemies. You'll be able to more easily kill them fast, and dodge their hits.
2. The last job has a ability which will wipe out all regular enemies, unless they get a First Strike. Just equip this ability and the Alarm Earrings.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, maintaining the Unscathed bonus is rather dependent on luck. The best thing you can do is equip one of your party members with the [Gale Hairpin] item. This accessory increases the chance of your party gaining the first strike by 10%. Also, you can give the [Alarm Earrings] accessory to another member. This item decreases the chance for enemies to gain first strike by 10%.

After gaining the first strike, a great strategy is to have a Templar use the [Rampart] skill. [Rampart] blocks the next incoming physical attack to each one of your party members. This will give you an extra turn to try to defeat your enemies without taking damage.